# fatal error call to undefined function svn_log()

Tags: php, svn

How to retrieve commit messages using php. Now i am using this code but it's giving error

> fatal error call to undefined function svn_log()

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r( svn_log('http://10.1.1.100:8080/svn/repos/php/', svn::HEAD) );

?>
```

Comment: it looks like the code example is incomplete.

Comment: So could you provide working example code

Answer (score 0):

Check in your php installation with `phpinfo();` if the [extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn) installed for SVN, you can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/svn.setup.php) the description

Create php file with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and search for SVN on the output like:
[image]

You can install SVN PHP package over [PECL here is a description how](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php)

Comment: plz explore your statement

Comment: thanks for reply. I have searched svn but did not get svn client version or svn extension version in phpinfo. So what is the solution for this ?

Comment: on php.net is a description how to install the extention http://php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php

Comment: Can you tell me? How to install extension via command in centos6 and i have already installed  when i check # svn --version then it shows mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.

Comment: there is a difference between the apache module and the php module, have no clue how the package name in centos is but in some other is it php-svn oder php-subversion

Comment: yum install subversion subversion-devel neon neon-devel
pecl install svn
echo "extension=svn.so" > /etc/php.d/svn.ini
now its working but when i stop lampp service...
service httpd restartd

Comment: i also mention log "fatal error" when i use my php code ....svn function is not working i am using it's with lamp when i stop /opt/lampp/lampp stop then its working because of this i have installed php-devel and a info.php file put on /var/www/html then it's showing svn client extension and svn extension version and working my php code. How can i integrate svn with lampp??

Comment: It is better to use the navie instaltion and not lampp, but if you use lampp you can install the php svn package over PECL...look at the link that I have posted before....http://php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php